# Where is the system llvm-config on macOS?

Tags: xcode, macos, llvm

If I'm not mistaken, the compiler etc. installed as part of XCode use llvm. But I can't find an llvm-config binary to generate proper flags for command-line compilation to an llvm target.  Where is such a thing on macOS?

I know I can install a new llvm via MacPorts or Homebrew, but I don't want to duplicate what's already there; I just want a way to get at the system configuration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

llvm-config is used to build programs that would link against LLVM.
Xcode does not distribute the LLVM libraries, and does not support linking against clang itself, so llvm-config is of no use in this context. What is your use case?

Comment: That was the missing piece.  I was attempting to build third-party software that wants to link against the llvm libs, but couldn't find the system ones.  Because there apparently aren't any, so Homebrew it is. Thanks!

Comment: The case is debug configuration during development in qt-creator.

Comment: This is my case as well (building Qt 5.15.11 from source). I'd prefer not Brew all of llvm, but if configure REALLY needs it (or thinks it does during its evaluation of the system, I guess I have to? I'll check for a switch that avoids this, and if there isn't one, I'll just take the (very lengthy) plunge.